# Ionic Http Request to object of class or to variable cascadding

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to get array of values from api and load it to class object and load them to select.

My problem is am not able to push the http requested data in to object

Tried Possibility

1. directly push data to object,
2. store in a temp and then push

i found many article and post regarding .map am not sure how to use it so tried to convert json to array data and store it

below are my code

am trying to do cascading one select to load another select data.

My api Resopnse

`{"data":{"data":[{"id":"1","name":"BCA 1"},{"id":"2","name":"BCA 2"},{"id":"3","name":"BCA 3"}],"status":"success","message":"Class Found"}}`

my expectation is

to load this json data from api

`{"id":"1","name":"BCA 1"},{"id":"2","name":"BCA 2"},{"id":"3","name":"BCA 3"}`

to `class` object

```
class: Class[];
temp:any=[];

class Class {
    public id: number;
    public name: string;
}

this.http.post(link, data).subscribe(
    data => {

        var obj = JSON.parse(data["_body"]); 

        this.temp.push(obj["data"]["data"]);

    }, 
    error => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error)); 
    });

this.temp.forEach(Data => {            
    this.class.push(Data);
});
```

console Output

```
{data: Array(3), status: "success", message: "Class Found"}
data: Array(3)
0: {id: "1", name: "BCA 1"}
1: {id: "2", name: "BCA 2"}
2: {id: "3", name: "BCA 3"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
message: "Class Found"
status: "success"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: What happens if you do something like this? `this.http.post(link, data).subscribe(
    response => {
        const body = response.json();
        console.log(body.data);
   },
   error => {
       console.log(error);
   });` (this is only to know what's printed in the console, I'm not adding the data to the array)

Comment: ok pasting the same and checking a moment

Comment: pasted the output odd console

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer, but please let me know if it doesn't work so that we can debug step by step and see what's wrong :)

Comment: sure thanks for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please let me know if this is not correct, but based on the comments, you should be able to get the `data` array by doing this:

```
public classArray: Array<Class> = [];

public yourMethod(): void {

    this.http.post(link, data).subscribe(
        response => {

            // Get the body of the response
            const body = response.json();

            // Get the data array within the data property
            const data = body.data.data;

            // This should print the data in the console
            console.log(data);

            // Add the items to the array
            this.classArray.push(...data);

            // This should print the classArray array in the console
            console.log(this.classArray);
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

---

**EDIT**

You can also use the `map` operator to get the body of the request, like this:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';

// ...

public classArray: Array<Class> = [];

public yourMethod(): void {

    this.http.post(link, data)
        .pipe(
            map(response => response.json())
        )        
        .subscribe(
            body => {

                // Get the data array within the data property
                const data = body.data.data;

                // This should print the data in the console
                console.log(data);

                // Add the items to the array
                this.classArray.push(...data);

                // This should print the classArray array in the console
                console.log(this.classArray);
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
}
```

Comment: insted of temp cant i push the data directly to array of class object it self i was not sure so was using temp to store it ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `class` array (I'd change the name to be something else like `classArray` just in case if the `class` word is a reserved name)

Comment: `(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "1", name: "BCA 1"}
1: {id: "2", name: "BCA 2"}
2: {id: "3", name: "BCA 3"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)`

Comment: Ok, so seems like is working properly, right? I mean, you now have the array in the `classArray` property.

Comment: just one question what is the difference between const body= and .map

Comment: What version of **angular** and **rxjs** are you using? (you can see that in the `package.json` file)

Comment: "rxjs": "5.5.11",  "@angular/core": "5.2.11",

Comment: ReferenceError: res is not defined

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste issue. Fixed

Comment: i am getting error like this CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object can you help when creating array

Comment: Sure. Can you please create a new question with all the relevant code?